# Is there a way to play audio and output them to 2 separate devices?

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, headphones, audio-output

For example a movie playing on the speakers and another video playing (on a possibly different player/program) on my headphones.

Is it possible to do this in Windows 7?

Comment: Am I correct in that you want to play 2 video/audio streams and have one go to the speakers and the other go to the headphones?

Comment: Thanks, yeah. So someone can watch a movie in the same computer but another display while I watch something else with my headphones in the main display.

Comment: There are some ways to do this. The most straight forward would be to tell your 2 video players to direct their audio to a certain output via their internal settings (most if not all video players allow this). For this I have to ask which two programs you plan to use

Comment: Thanks I could use MPC-HC and kmp or all MPC. VLC would work too.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in VLC. Just open your videos in separate windows and adjust the settings:

Open Tools -> Preferences (set Show Settings to All).

If you use DirectX, then go to Audio -> Output modules -> DirectX and Output device.

If you use Waveout, then go toAudio -> Output modules -> WaveOut and Select Audio Device.

Remember to press Save to save VLC settings and restart VLC after that to make sure changes are enable

(From [VLC help "Change output device in case of multiple audio devices"](https://wiki.videolan.org/Change_output_device_in_case_of_multiple_audio_devices/))

Comment: Posting just a link is not appreciated here. External links may go away. It's best to include the essential information here, I have done that for you now.